# Why does TS Lose Type Inferences When Spreading

Tags: typescript, types, type-assertion

### Update 1️⃣

As per comments, I did create a standalone example of what seems to be the same situation:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type People = Person[];

const p: Person = {
  name: "Mark",
  age: 39,
};

const people: People = [p];

const anotherP = {
  ...people[0],
  age: 40,
};
```

However...this doesn't create any issue!

So, now the issues might be from the actual types from: `import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';`.

Anyway, `as` seems to be the way to go for this particular situation.

---

Consider:

```
const meta = {
  args: {
    items: [
      {
        isValid: null,
        stepNumber: '1',
        text: 'Customer Information',

        children: 'Content',
      },
    ],
  },
```

If I remove 1️⃣ of the s, I get the expected pushback from TS. This confirms that the types are all good in the provided snippet.

However, further along in the code I have:

```
export const Valid: StoryObj<typeof meta> = {
  args: {
    items: [
      {
        ...meta.args.items[0],
        isValid: true,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

In this part specifically:

```
{
        ...meta.args.items[0],
        isValid: true,
      },
```

TS says, "Type `{ isValid: true; stepNumber?: string | undefined; text?: string | undefined; children?: string | undefined; }` is not assignable to type `CheckoutAccordionItemProps`.
Types of property `stepNumber` are incompatible.
Type `string | undefined` is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type `undefined` is not assignable to type `string`..."

For more visibility ️, here's this:

```
export interface CheckoutAccordionItemProps {
  isValid: boolean | null;
  stepNumber: string;
  text: string;

  children: ReactNode;
}
```

To summarize, even though:

```
args: {
    items: [
      {
        isValid: null,
        stepNumber: '1',
        text: 'Customer Information',

        children: 'Content',
      },
    ],
  },
```

is fine, the act of spreading:         `...meta.args.items[0],` seems to introduce `undefined` possibilities.

This can be resolved by using:        `...(meta.args.items[0] as CheckoutAccordionItemProps),`.

Why do we need to use this ugly  **type assertion** `as`? **Spreading** should not have compromised the original type information.

Comment: What's `StoryObj`?  Could you [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to directly see the issue you're seeing without unrelated problems like missing declarations?

Comment: `import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';`. It's from _Storybook._ None of that affects the general question. However, let me see if after some time, I can just simplify the point here with a 'generic' person or such.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we spread an **object** with *TypeScript,* it doesn't just take the values and keys at face value. Instead, *TypeScript* tries to represent the types of the output object as accurately as possible, including the possibility that some keys might not exist on the source object even if they do at runtime, resulting in `undefined` being a 'possibility.'

```js
{
    ...meta.args.items[0],
    isValid: true,
}
```

*TypeScript* interprets this as "Take all properties from `meta.args.items[0]` and add/overwrite the `isValid` property with the value `true`". But *TypeScript* doesn't guarantee that all properties of `meta.args.items[0]` exist (even if we know that they do). It adds the possibility of `undefined` to each of them.

```js
{
    isValid: true;
    stepNumber?: string | undefined;
    text?: string | undefined;
    children?: string | undefined;
}
```

This is a safe behavior because in JavaScript, if you were to spread an object that didn't have one of the expected keys, the resulting object would indeed have that key set to `undefined`.

We're forced to use a type assertion to tell TypeScript, "Trust me, I know what I'm doing".

```js
{
    ...(meta.args.items[0] as CheckoutAccordionItemProps),
    isValid: true,
}
```